# Get values for jVectormap. getElementbyID is not working

Tags: javascript, php, json, getelementbyid, jvectormap

I try to set markers in a jVectormap. I get the content from my database and write it in a hidden input field. Return in the following format:

```
{latLng:[52.5200066,13.404954],name:'Berlin'},{latLng:[53.0792962,8.8016937],name:'Bremen'},{latLng:[49.8728253,8.6511929],name:'Darmstadt'},{latLng:[50.1109221,8.6821267],name:'Frankfurt'},{latLng:[53.5510846,9.9936818],name:'Hamburg'},{latLng:[54.3232927,10.1227652],name:'Kiel'},{latLng:[50.937531,6.9602786],name:'Köln'},{latLng:[48.30694,14.28583],name:'Linz'},{latLng:[48.1351253,11.5819806],name:'München'},{latLng:[53.6355022,11.4012499],name:'Schwerin'},{latLng:[48.7758459,9.1829321],name:'Stuttgart'},{latLng:[48.0689177,11.6212533],name:'Unterhaching'},,{latLng:[48.2081743,16.3738189],name:'Wien'},
```

If i want to read this field nothing happens. If I copy and paste this line to the javascript section everything is fine.

This is working:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var map,
          markers = [
            {latLng:[52.5200066,13.404954],name:'Berlin'},{latLng:[53.0792962,8.8016937],name:'Bremen'},{latLng:[49.8728253,8.6511929],name:'Darmstadt'},{latLng:[50.1109221,8.6821267],name:'Frankfurt'},{latLng:[53.5510846,9.9936818],name:'Hamburg'},{latLng:[54.3232927,10.1227652],name:'Kiel'},{latLng:[50.937531,6.9602786],name:'Köln'},{latLng:[48.30694,14.28583],name:'Linz'},{latLng:[48.1351253,11.5819806],name:'München'},{latLng:[53.6355022,11.4012499],name:'Schwerin'},{latLng:[48.7758459,9.1829321],name:'Stuttgart'},{latLng:[48.0689177,11.6212533],name:'Unterhaching'},,{latLng:[48.2081743,16.3738189],name:'Wien'},

          ],
```

This is not working:

```
$(function(){
        var map,
          markers = [
            document.getElementById("geodata").value; 

          ],
```

Where´s my problem? :(

Comment: you have JSON not DOM .. so getElementById (that work on DOM element )  can't work ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I changed everything a different times and now it´s almost working.

I have now "divs" instead of an input. I changed my php function and return the correct JSON-Formt (This was my mistake in the first try)

Here is the javascript code:

```
function GET_PLACES(){
    var result_numbers = document.getElementById("result_numbers").value -1;
    var text = "";
    var result = "";
    for (i = 1; i < result_numbers + 2; i++) {
        text = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("geodata"+i).innerHTML);
    }
    return text;
}
console.log(GET_PLACES());
alert(JSON.stringify(GET_PLACES()));
$(function(){
        var map,

          markers = [GET_PLACES()],
```

...

The last problem i have, is that it only returs the last found JSON from the loop.

### How can an build an array that contains all found JSON objects?

UPDATE ... Here is the solution

```
function GET_PLACES(){
    var result_numbers = document.getElementById("result_numbers").value -1;
    var text = "";
    var result = [];
    for (i = 1; i < result_numbers + 2; i++) {
        text = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("geodata"+i).innerHTML);
        result.push(text);
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(GET_PLACES());
alert(JSON.stringify(GET_PLACES()));
$(function(){
        var map,

          markers = GET_PLACES(),
```

Answer (score 0):

The value that is in the input is a JSON string, not an object, so you must parse it to an object:

```
$(function(){
        var map,
          markers = [
            JSON.parse(document.getElementById("geodata").value); 

          ],
```

Comment: yes, right way. Thank you, but it´s unfortunately not working. Console says "JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 ". It seems that my coordinates in brackets are the problem ... mhhh :/

Comment: Then, the value in the input is not a well formated json value. Do a `console.log (document.getElementById("geodata").value);` to see what is there and let me know